# toggle an icon in ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, icons, toggle

In the following code I am attempting to show a plus sign [+] for a series of regions. When the user clicks the plus sign the sub regions appear below AND the plus sign changes to a minus [-] sign.

The regions are displayed correctly and when the link is clicked the sub regions are displayed correctly. However, I cannot seem to get show/hide to work for the plus and minus and I need the sub regions to hide when the user clicks the minus to collapse the list again.

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in vm.Regions track by $index">
    {{item1}}
    <a ng-click="vm.expandIt(item1)">
        <span>[+]</span> 
        <span>[-]</span>
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox" />

    <div ng-if="vm.collapseId==item1" ng-repeat="item2 in vm.data | filter:{'Region':  item1}:true">
        {{item2.CCG}}<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item2.Selected" />
    </div>

</div>
```

The `expandIt` function looks like this:

```
function expandIt(item) {
  vm.collapseId = item;
  console.log(`expand called!:${vm.collapseId}`)
}
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What you are trying to create is called an `Accordion`. You can find many components already created. Also, `ng-click="vm.expandIt(item1)` should be on `<span>[+]</span>` and vice-versa on `<span>[-]</span>`

Comment: if this is your criteria to show the region: `ng-if="vm.collapseId==item1"` (i guess only one region can be opened), you can try in `expandIt` function: `vm.collapseId = (vm.collapseId == item) ? false : item;` which will alternate the value if already set to this value

Comment: yes, that helped, thanks guys.. getting there. Will try the answer just in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<a ng-click="vm.expandIt(item1)">
    <span>{{item1.label}}</span> 
</a>
```

Where `label` is defined to `[+]` or `[-]` according to the status of the item.

Another way could be:

```
<a ng-click="vm.expandIt(item1)">
    <span ng-if="!item1.expanded">[+]</span> 
    <span ng-if="item1.expanded">[-]</span>
</a>
```

Where `expanded` is the status of your item1.

Comment: Though this is one of the way, just update the name of the function as `expandIt` for hide sounds wrong.

Comment: I agree, I would rather rename `toggleItem` or something that implies both the expand and the collapse actions.

Comment: I went with the second option in the answer since I prefer to keep the markup in the file. Thanks for your help guys. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped you ;) have a nice day!